# Input string not in correct format error in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string

I am storing one string in an Oracle database table with a column type `CLOB`.

The string which is inserted in table -

```
"The string is {{?/*}}"
```

Also in database it is stored as above.

I want the string to be shown on UI -

```
"The string is {?/*}"
```

NOTE - I have used one extra opening and closing curly braces because `{` and `}` are escape characters.

I am calling this string in C# code in two different pages. On one page, it is working perfectly fine without any error, i.e the string which I want to see in the UI -

```
   "The string is {?/*}"
```

But on the second page, it I get this below error:

(System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(String name)
at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.d__15.MoveNext()
at System.Web.Mvc.ModelValidator.CompositeModelValidator.d__1.MoveNext()
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model)
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)

How can this be solved?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Are both pages using same data type CLOB?  Are both pages storing in same Data Table in database?

Comment: @jdweng Yes, they are using same data type CLOB and both pages are storing the same data table in Database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.